# Redis hyperlog keys cardinality is not increasing

Tags: redis, hyperloglog

When using a hyperlog key in redis master slave 4.0.9 we have a `pfcount` of `52161862`.

Now when we add a unique item through `pfadd` it is returning zero and of count is still `52161862`.

Any idea why we are not able to add more unique items to this key?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperloglog is **NOT** an accurate counting, instead, the result of `PFCOUNT` is approximated with a standard error of 0.81%. So when you add a new unique item, the result might be unchanged.